# Actionscript 2.0, Having a SendAndLoad() function Issue

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flash, actionscript

I have this code:

```
btn_jouer.onRelease = function ()
{
    verif = txt_email_user.text;
    if (txt_email_user.text == "")
    {
        txt_erreur.textColor = 16724736;
        txt_erreur.text = "Champ(s) manquant(s)";
    }
    else if (verif.indexOf("@", 0) == -1 || verif.indexOf(".", 0) == -1)
    {
        txt_erreur.textColor = 16724736;
        txt_erreur.text = "Adresse E-mail invalide";
    }
    else
    {
        php_login = new LoadVars();
        php_login.email = txt_email_user.text;
        php_login.sendAndLoad(_root.page_Login, php_login, "POST");
        php_login.onLoad = function(succes)
        {
            if (succes)
            {
        //txt_erreur.text = php_login.etat;
        //return;
                if (php_login.etat == "exist")
                {
                    _root.var_user.id = php_login.id;
                    _root.var_user.nom = php_login.nom;
                    _root.var_user.prenom = php_login.prenom;
                    _root.var_user.score = php_login.score;
                    _root.MovieLogin.unloadMovie();
                    if (_root._root.selectedPhone == "KS360")
                    {
                        _root.gotoAndStop(4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _root.gotoAndStop(3);
                    } // end else if
                }
                else if (php_login.etat == "non")
                {
                    trace (php_login.etat);
                    txt_erreur.text = "Email non enregistré! veuillez vous s'inscrir";
                } // end if
            } // end else if
        };
    } // end else if
};
```

The "page_Login" is login.php file on the server,
After debugging, the file login.php successfully received Posted data so i got:
$_POST['email'] = "what ever you type in swf form";

The login.php processor file:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
    $email = strtolower(addslashes($_REQUEST['email']));
    $DB->_request("select * from gamers where email='$email'");
    if($DB->_nr() > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($DB->Result);
        echo "&etat=exist&nom={$row['nom']}&prenom={$row['prenom']}&score={$row['score']}";
        //
        exit;
    }
    else {
        echo "&etat=non";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Here above, the $DB->_nr() always returns "0" even the email address exists!

I have tried to create a simple html page having a form with method POST and have a simple input type text with a name="email"
When i write my email which is valid in the database and hit submit $DB->_nr() returns 1.

This really is driving me crazy, i'm sure that the email address exists, the login.php page receive posted data "email = validemail@domain.com" from SendAndLoad(); but mysql_num_rows returns 0.

Any one there had the same issue??
Any help would be so much appreciated!

Barry,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in PHP to compare the email in both cases: given from flash and from HTML form:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
    //createa the testFile.txt and give it attributes with 0777 for permission (in case you are under linux)
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "-".$_REQUEST['email']."-\r\n");
    fclose($fh);

    $email = strtolower(addslashes($_REQUEST['email']));
    $DB->_request("select * from gamers where email='$email'");
    if($DB->_nr() > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($DB->Result);
        echo "&etat=exist&nom={$row['nom']}&prenom={$row['prenom']}&score={$row['score']}";
        //
        exit;
    }
    else {
        echo "&etat=non";
        exit;
    }
}
```

if you test for both of the cases, you will be able to compare the two exact forms. I have put "-" in the front and the end of it just to see if there are any whitespaces next to the email value.

Please reply with a compare result. thank you.